# Azure WebApps to CloudService Communications

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-web-app-service

I have several WebApp clients that will be used to serve authenticated users via TLS. On the backend these WebApps communicate to a CloudService via NetTCP using WCF on **cloudapp.net** endpoints. Both sets of resources are on the same Azure subscription, resource group and geographic location.

My question is in regards to both performance as well as security:

**1.** Will traffic between the WebApp and CloudService resources stay within the Azure infrastructure to maintain the best performance? If not is there a way to ensure the fastest possible communication between the WebApps and CloudServices?

**2.** If the traffic does remain internal then are there any concerns about securing the traffic when these calls are made or can I safely keep the calls as **http://** requests since they will not be made on any public channels?

**3.** Are there any other security or performance concerns regarding this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

1. Not, unless you implement [VNet integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) and integrate your WebApp into the CloudService VNet.
2. Well, it depends on how paranoid you are, if you *absolutely* trust Azure, you can use `HTTP`, without `S`. I'm not sure how secure that is, but I can imagine no one would say: "Use HTTP, Azure (or whatever) is secure enough".
3. If everything is in one region, it should be fine, theoretically.

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer to question 1. You can certainly communicate between different Azure services without leaving Azure's infrastructure (traffic stays within the region). And with question 3: I don't see how you can say everything is fine because it's within a region (performance can be affected by VM size, for example).

Comment: 1. Why would WebApp talk to something through the backplane without VNet integration? 3. This scenario doesn't add anything special to the model of the asker. Of course there are performance and security considerations, but the are general, not related to the described scenario

Comment: Well... the question was asking about where the traffic goes. And it doesn't need a Vnet to stay within the region. My point is that a vnet isn't a required component for intra-region communication (yes, there are security advantages - that part I am not arguing at all). And there are cases where services are accessible both from an internal property (e.g. web app) and external resource (on-premises app, dev/test tools, etc).

Comment: Thanks David. Is there a way to lock down my CloudServices and/or the WCF endpoints running on them to only accept calls from within an Azure region? I'm looking for something similar to how Azure SQL Server handles their automatic white listing of internal Azure resources. I feel like a Vnet is overkill for my needs, but making the endpoints inaccessible to public channels might fit the bill nicely...